# Mediawiki memory exhausing at 12MB while limit is at 2GB

Tags: php, apache, http, mediawiki, shared-hosting

I have tried numerous times to install MediaWiki on my website. Using the latest version (1.22.0) with manual installation I have not achieved any success.

It installs fine, and everything during the installation is reported with 'OK'. There are no errors regarding memory usage at that point, and my memory limit in PHP has been defined to 2048MB which really should be enough.

Here's the catch: when I log in into my own wiki, the page goes into 'endless-load' mode and the php_error log shows this:

```
[26-Dec-2013 04:20:31 CST6CDT] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 12320768) (tried to allocate 28834 bytes) in /home/velocit1/public_html/bartpelle.com/infowiki/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 1191
[26-Dec-2013 04:20:32 CST6CDT] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 12058624) (tried to allocate 116268 bytes) in /home/velocit1/public_html/bartpelle.com/infowiki/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 1191
[26-Dec-2013 04:20:42 CST6CDT] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 12320768) (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/velocit1/public_html/bartpelle.com/infowiki/includes/cache/CacheDependency.php on line 331
```

This happens when I try to log in *and* when I try to create an account. Every page becomes inaccessible at this point until I clear my cookies, so the session is lost.

I have tried setting memory limits to different height, both in the software by setting the **$wgMemoryLimit** to various sizes, and internally in the PHP configuration. Nothing so far has helped me out.

Comment: What limit does `phpinfo()` give you?

Comment: @Pekka 2048MB, as specified. :(

Comment: I'm not sure this is the memory limit, though. Could it be you have simply run out of actual memory? [PHP out of memory error even though memory_limit not reached](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13955914)

Comment: The server I use is a shared hoster with ~80GB of RAM. I can see in my control panel that the usage of all users together is far below the maximum.

Comment: Maybe the web host has imposed some restrictions outside the memory limit? What do you get when checking available RAM from the command line? (`free` should do the job)

Comment: I already contacted my hoster but they confirmed that I was not physically running out of memory, nor the server. That's why I thought it could be something software-related.

Comment: Can you check the available RAM?

Comment: Yes, it's more than 40GB... Doubt that'd be the problem :\

Comment: You have checked on the command line? Ideally as the user PHP runs as?

Comment: Take a look at the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13967541) to the post Pekka linked to: maybe your webserver has some memory use limits configured, or maybe PHP or your whole webserver is running under [ulimit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ulimit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can't really answer without knowing what Ilmari asked, but my wild guess would be that this has to do with the [changes to the job queue in 1.22](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Changes_introduced_in_MediaWiki_1.22).

Try increasing [`$wgMaxShellMemory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:$wgMaxShellMemory) too in your `LocalSettings.php` and try to [get a job queue crontab running](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Set_up).