# Wordpress home page is blank but every other page is working fine

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to move an existing site that works fine on the old server to a new server. On the new server the homepage is just showing blank page. however when i navigate to "wp-admin" or other pages like "about-us" shoiws up just fine and i am also able to login in my wp-admin. It's just the homepage that is blank..

I have tried to `enable debug` and also tried looking into wp_content/debug.php and it's empty:

```
define('WP_DEBUG',true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',true);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','256M');
```

Next thing i tried is the `permalink` settings -> permalink -> "save" it also didn't work.

I have also tried by switching php version `php7.3` same as the old server, didn't help

then finally i tried removing the `plugins` one by one and figured after removing this particular elementor plugin (https://www.eletemplator.com/ele-custom-skin/) the home page was loading fine. However this plugin is very important as most of the pages are using templates from this plugin to display the content.

Now that I know this plugin is causing the issue on the new server could it be because of the loading time? with this plugin on the old server everything works fine.

hope someone can help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the solutions, finally came to understanding that it was a memory limit issue on the httpd.conf apache server setting. After increasing the limit for `RLimitMEM = 204535125` it was working!

this link really helped! incase someone faces this issue in the future please look into the httpd.conf settings for the memory limit. Further reference from a previously asked similar question: [PHP out of memory error even though memory_limit not reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955914/php-out-of-memory-error-even-though-memory-limit-not-reached)

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this issue you can choose following steps:

1: First you try to disabling all the plugins of yours and then see if the front end comes back. If you can’t do it from the backend due to any reason, you can as well rename /plugins/ folder to /plugins-broken/ or similar, using FTP access.

2: If it does, then start enabling plugins one by one until the issue reappears. Then you’ll know what caused it.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! i tried all that and i finally ended up noticing it was the memory issue on the server settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a blank `index.html` file in the root WordPress directory. Deleting the blank `index.html` fixed the issue.