# TCPDF Does not create pdf When data is in huge amount

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am working with `tcpdf` to generate report in `pdf`. when i generate report for `one month` it gives me the error and it only genereates 15 pages in pdf not more than that.

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 85721088) (tried to allocate 262142 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 20732

How to resolve this issues `tcpdf` not creating more than 15 pages. Please Help me to resolve this issue I am stuck on it. I want More pages to genrate to show all data.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please check out this post on dealing with PHP memory issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955914/php-out-of-memory-error-even-though-memory-limit-not-reached

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues that you need to address when dealing with TCPDF,

The first is setting the max amount of memory you feel appropriate and require using something like this.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','VALUE HERE');
```

Then you need to ensure that you have sufficent processing time;

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', VALUE HERE);
```

It is then a very good idea to check all your code, looking for ways to limit the amount of resources required to create the pdf. In my case, I had lots of DB results, and multiple arrays storing huge volumes of data which remained in memory after they had been used.  Once I unset these after their usage, my memory usage reduced considerably.